# How does QList decide whether to store pointers or the items themselves?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qlist

From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html#details):

> Internally, QList is represented as an array of pointers to items
>   of type T. If T is itself a pointer type or a basic type that is no
>   larger than a pointer, or if T is one of Qt's shared classes, then
>   QList stores the items directly in the pointer array.

I'm interested to know, how does `QList` 'decide' whether to store pointers or the items themselves depending on the type?

Do they do it using some esoteric template syntax?

Comment: since you define your list as: ``QList<int>`` or ``QList<int*>`` or even ``QList<myBigStructureTypeThingy>`` you tell QList what type you will be storing. If this type is in size equal or less than a pointer it will store the whole variable, otherwise the lookup array will only consist of pointers to variables. The list itself would then consist of the lookup-array and a data-memory-area (if QList<NoPointerType>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's read the source (I'm using Qt 4.8).

**qlist.h**:

```
struct Node { 
    void *v;
#if defined(Q_CC_BOR)
    Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE T &t();
#else
    Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE T &t()
    { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic
                                   ? v : this); }
#endif
};
```

`QList` uses `QTypeInfo` to determine type properties. `QTypeInfo` is declared for various types separately. In **qglobal.h**:

Default declaration for unknown type:

```
template <typename T>
class QTypeInfo
{
public:
    enum {
        isPointer = false,
        isComplex = true,
        isStatic = true,
        isLarge = (sizeof(T)>sizeof(void*)),
        isDummy = false
    };
};
```

Declaration for pointers:

```
template <typename T>
class QTypeInfo<T*>
{
public:
    enum {
        isPointer = true,
        isComplex = false,
        isStatic = false,
        isLarge = false,
        isDummy = false
    };
};
```

Macros for convenient type info declaration:

```
#define Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO_BODY(TYPE, FLAGS) \
class QTypeInfo<TYPE > \
{ \
public: \
    enum { \
        isComplex = (((FLAGS) & Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE) == 0), \
        isStatic = (((FLAGS) & (Q_MOVABLE_TYPE | Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE)) == 0), \
        isLarge = (sizeof(TYPE)>sizeof(void*)), \
        isPointer = false, \
        isDummy = (((FLAGS) & Q_DUMMY_TYPE) != 0) \
    }; \
    static inline const char *name() { return #TYPE; } \
}

#define Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(TYPE, FLAGS) \
template<> \
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO_BODY(TYPE, FLAGS)
```

Declaration for primitive types:

```
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(bool, Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE);
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(char, Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE); /* ... */
```

Also it's defined for specific Qt types, e.g. in **qurl.h**:

```
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(QUrl, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE);
```

Or in **qhash.h**:

```
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(QHashDummyValue, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE | Q_DUMMY_TYPE);
```

When `QList` uses `QTypeInfo<T>`, the compiler picks up the closest of present `QTypeInfo` definitions.

Comment: So `Node::t()` is the function that does the magic. Depending on `QTypeInfo` it dereferences either the stored 32-bit value or the `this` pointer itself. Thanks for the insight!